# How to populate a Form Select from Model in Zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

This question ask before. But either question/solution related to using fieldset Or they are older and using techniques from ZF2 earlier releases. Now I am aware of http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html . But there solution is related to bind a fieldset to form using FormElementManager. This is also true for most of recent question regrading create a dynamic form dropdown.

But I have a form with 3 dropdown fields which get data from DB. Until now I have option to pass DB Adapter to constructor of Form from Controller. But now I want to use more better way to populate dropdown preferably FormElementManager but without using Fieldsets.

If it really possible to build such system ?

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the DB adapter dependancy via a factory. The following config would be either within your Module.php or in a config file. You can inject your DB adapter or objectManager and retrieve your form object from the service manager elsewhere in your application from any service manager aware class.

```
public function getFormElementConfig()
    {
        return array(

            'factories' => array(
                'MyForm' => function (ServiceManager $sm)
                {
                    $form = new \MyNamespace\MyForm($sm->get('my_db_adapter'));
                    return $form;
                },
                   )
    }
```

This form is now available via the service locator from any service aware class:

```
$serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager')->get('MyForm');
```

With the DB Adapter dependancy already injected via the factory.

To access the object from your controller you might like to consider creating a Controller Plugin to keep the ServiceManager object out of your Controller class.

```
//MyController.php
public function myAction(){
//retrieve form via plugin with the DB adapter already set
$myForm=$this->myForm();
}
```

Comment: This will not work, As All form element initialization done in constructor which is called first. So DB Adapter not set on that time. So code will throw error.

Comment: you can easily pass your DB adapter in the forms constructor in the same way, see edited answer above:

$form = new \MyNamespace\MyForm($sm->get('my_db_adapter'));

Comment: This approach would work, But here a caveat, I need to pass Models instead of DB Adapter as Code Quality demands. Then As form need more dynamic dropdowns, as constructor have more arguments (Like `__construct(ModelA, ModelB, ModelC, ModelD)`) which look ugly. Passing them in array also have same level of ugliness.

Comment: What about if I pass ServiceManager and get Model Instances into Model.

Comment: You only asked about the DB adapter so my example shows how to do that. I'm not sure why you would want to pass lots if individual Models like this. Surely from your DBAdapter you can then query the relevant Repositories from within your Form or create a Custom Select object with the logic there instead. If you were to use Doctrine ORM for example you could use ObjectSelect:

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Form/Element/ObjectSelect.php

This is a custom Form element extending Select and populating the options via a proxy, in your case DB repository

Comment: In discussed ZF2 link for advance use of forms, Model class is passed to FieldSet. That approach is recommended. So It look good to pass Model Class instead of DB Adapter. I am confused here, As I agreed with your approach here, But also like that approach too.

Comment: I think you may be confusing the Model which is passed to hyrdate the form/fieldset as opposed to passing an ObjectManager/DbAdapter to hydrate a specific element such as a Select or RadioGroup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60740/discussion-between-matwr-and-kuldeep-kamboj).